# deadlink / expired link in answers or outdated answers are not revised

Tags: discussion

some questions hold a deadlink in StackOverflow and many places. it holds a deadlink because the discussion started by the original poster and the link is used by the responders no longer exist as it is changed by the original vendors' eg. oracle, aws and also there are cases for answers that are outdated.

so what will be the solution for such deadlink// expired link and outdated answers ?

Comment: Where it makes sense (e.g. pointing to documentation), the link could be edited to point to Archive.org (if it was archived there). If you know the location it moved to, of course preferably the link should be adjusted to that. If the said software is no longer distributed – well, that's the way of things: recommend a replacement if you know, or leave a comment to maybe raise the author who might know. But there's no way to keep historical links alive. And yes, things "age out" – some software has a fast pace…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so what will be the solution for such deadlink // expired link

Stack Exchange should use https://web.archive.org/.